# Android Native error "/system/lib/libdvm.so"

Tags: android, java-native-interface

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 D AEE/AED : coredump_socket_create: 26233

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED : $** *****       **Exception**       ***** **$

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED : Build Info:

'ALPS.JB2.TDD.MP:HBJ2.0:MT6589:S01,Xiaomi/2013022/HM2013022:4.2.1/HM2013022/JHACNBA13.0:user/release-keys'

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED : Flavor Info: 'None'

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED : Exception Log Time:[Tue Oct 21 23:10:32 GMT 2014] 
[68351.030000]

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED : Exception Class: Native (NE)

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED : Exception Type: SIGSEGV

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED : Current Executing Process:

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :   pid: 26233, tid: 26263

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :   com.example.testgame:service

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED : Backtrace:

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :     #00  pc 00024628  /system/lib/libc.so

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :     #01  pc 00019fb8  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+5612)

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :     #02  pc 0000cb48  /system/lib/libc.so (free+16)

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :     #03  pc 00009395  /system/lib/libcutils.so

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :     #04  pc 0000a1b7  /system/lib/libcutils.so (localtime_tz+50)

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :     #05  pc 0004e3e1

/system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::Time::set(long long)+30)

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :     #06  pc 000697d3
/system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :     #07  pc 0001e4d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :     #08  pc 0004ddc1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+500)

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :     #09  pc 000278a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :     #10  pc 0002b804  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :     #11  pc 00061095  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :     #12  pc 000610bf  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED :     #13  pc 00055725  /system/lib/

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 I AEE/AED : $** *****       **Exception**       ***** **$

10-21 23:10:32.362 26265 26265 D AEE/AED : aed_report_dumpstate: filepath

/data/aee_exp/temp/db.H26265, pid 26233, tid 26263, exp_class 1, db_opt 0

Comment: That is the Dalvik Virtual Machine kicking the bucket

Comment: @mach - nope, it's the C library.  The question is who set it up to fail by giving it something bad (probably a null native pointer).  Where's the rest of the trace, with the registers?